# Converting a List of Enums into Flags in C#

Tags: c#, enums

I'm currently using a hotkey package that takes a set of `Key` and `ModifierKey` enumerations as flags.

As an example, this would register the `Ctrl+Shift+4` hotkey:

`hotKey = new GlobalHotKey.HotKey(Key.D4, ModifierKeys.Shift | ModifierKeys.Control);`

From my understanding, when passing in an enumeration as a flag, it's actually just performing a bitwise `or` operation (hence the syntax).

For my UI, I need to store keypresses in a `List<Key>`.  However, I eventually need to set the pressed keys as a new hotkey, and I need to convert my `List<Key>` to a plain old `Key` (with the flags operation).

Because I thought it was just a bitwise `or` operation, I attempted this solution with LINQ.

`hotkeysPressedBitwise = hotkeysPressed.Select(f => f).Aggregate((x, y) => x | y);`

where `hotkeysPressed` is my `List<Key>`.  My LINQ statement works correctly, however, it is not giving me the desired effect when actually passing it into my function.

For instance, when I pass in `X` and `C`, my LINQ statement returns a value equal to `X | C`.  If I cast that to the `Key` enum, it gives me the `F22` key for some reason.

`hotKey = new GlobalHotKey.HotKey( keys , ModifierKeys.None);`  doesn't work.  (I set ModifierKeys to none for now out of similicity).

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to [System.Windows.Forms.Keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.110).aspx) enum.

If you check the MSDN documentation for the [Keys enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2), you'll see the following warning:

> Do not use the values in this enumeration for combined bitwise
>   operations. The values in the enumeration are not mutually exclusive.

As far as I can tell, the only values of the Keys enum that can be combined with other values are *Shift*, *Ctrl* and *Alt*.

See an extract from the enum:

```
[Flags]
[TypeConverter(typeof(KeysConverter))]
public enum Keys
{
    ...
    A = 65,
    B = 66,
    C = 67,
    ...
    Shift = 65536,
    Control = 131072,
    Alt = 262144
}
```

Comment: Drats!  I knew there had to be something I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Hotkeys aren't usually designed to allow multiple *regular* keys (such as the letters X and C) in a combination, in contrast to *modifier* keys (such as control, shift, alt) which can be combined.

Because of this, `Key` enumerations won't usually work in a predictable way when using bitwise operations on regular keys, as they will be assigned sequential values, whereas modifier keys will have values that are powers-of-two